# Is there a way to trak variable ID with Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have script witch test web app:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe")
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://website.com")
driver.find_element_by_id('user-email').send_keys("LOGIN")
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("PASSWORD" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("ext-element-1234").click()
```

and I have problem with last ruler - this app has varieble page IDs, so with every page refresh app generates other ID name (ext-element-1235, ext-element-1236, ext-element-1237, ext-element-1238, and so on....), so it is imposible to test this app, because Python always say that "no such element: Unable to locate"

Is there a way to track it in other way? Xpath is useless too, because it is also variable as the ID.
Maybe it is a way to list it and tell Python to ignore ID when it does not exist and try to track other from list?

Comment: `"Xpath is useless too, because it is also variable..."`. What do you mean? Share XPath that you've tried

Comment: //button[@id='ext-element-1234'] (numbers are random with every refresh

Comment: @matsi Does the class name change?

Comment: @Sushil no, but above are other buttons with the same class name

Comment: Ok...Can u share the relevant html code of the website?

Comment: '<button class="x-button-el" type="button" id="ext-element-1235" data-componentid="ext-button-140"></button>'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Common solution for your case is to use just *static* part of ID and ignore *dynamic* part:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ext-element-')]").click()
```

Comment: 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.'

Comment: @matsi , I'm not sure that my code line can be a reason for this exception. Please check again

Comment: ok, it works! but it clicks on other button witch is above - 'ext-element-1', so I think that I can not provide selenium tests on this app, shame

Comment: @matsi , if it clicks on first button and you need second try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[starts-with(@id, 'ext-element-')]")[1].click()`

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to assist if I had a better understanding of what this element is, how it's named and why the name changes every time. I do believe that you can solve your problem by getting multiple elements and then scanning through them to identify the one whose id matches your naming convention (assuming you don't have multiple elements like that.) [if you look at the documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/) there are multiple ways of doing this. So basically the recommendation is to figure out the best way to filter out the element you want (ie get a list of all elements that match a criteria that the element you want will match but as few other elements will match as possible.) Then iterate through the returned list of elements and see if the element's id looks like it should. Given your write up this may be as simple as `if element.get_id()[:12] == "ext-element-":process(element)` (Note that I am not sure which selenium method you need to use to get the id from an element my example should be taken as pseudo code.)

Comment: it is a Button on witch I want to click

<button class="x-button-el" type="button" id="ext-element-1235" data-componentid="ext-button-140" xpath="1"></button>

I do not know whi its id is changing, I think that it is some Javascript witch generates various names (4) for its ID

Comment: Does the `class_name` change?

Comment: as Sushil pointed out if the class_name doesn't change it is likely not used by many other elements, you could also filter on all the buttons or just get all the elements on the page. Are there any other elements named according to the ext-element-12345 convention? You may need to check more than one criteria. When you say you don't know why the id is changing, do you not have access to the source code or a contact who does to ask? Why are you testing this app?